# How to align Text next to TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, layout

I have a `Text` widget (the +357) next to a `TextFormField` widget (the 12345678) like here:
[image]

They are put in a row (with the icon as well).

The problem is when there is error text in the `TextFormField`, the error text displaces the `TextFormField` entirely:

[image]

How can I keep the `TextFormField` in its place even when there is an error text to be displayed??

note: if it turns that showing some code is needed just ask about it, as I think that I explained it clearly above.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the property `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to your row

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
        ...                      
    ],
),
```